# R: Same clusters in k-means besides different settings for nstart and iter.max

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

Why do I get the same clustering although I use (very) different settings for `iter.max` and `nstart` of `kmeans()`?

```
set.seed(1)
ff_1 <- kmeans(faithful, 2, iter.max = 1, nstart = 1)

set.seed(1)
ff_2 <- kmeans(faithful, 2, iter.max = 2, nstart = 1)

set.seed(1)
ff_300 <- kmeans(faithful, 2, iter.max = 300, nstart = 300)

identical(ff_1, ff_2) # TRUE
identical(ff_1, ff_300) # TRUE
```

My real goal is to visualize the convergence of k-means clustering (for educational purposes) by comparing the clustering of one iteration with the clustering of say 2, 3 or 10 iterations. That's why I included the `set.seed` lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial centroids for `kmeans` are chosen randomly and since

(1)  you have the same random seed = 1 chosen in all the cases (which will force the exactly same centroids chosen for all the cases) and

(2) the clusters are quite separable you are getting the same results in the the cases (converges happen pretty fast, after the 1st iteration).

The following figure shows it.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
ff_1 <- kmeans(faithful, 2, iter.max = 1, nstart = 1)

set.seed(1)
ff_2 <- kmeans(faithful, 2, iter.max = 2, nstart = 1)

set.seed(1)
ff_300 <- kmeans(faithful, 2, iter.max = 300, nstart = 300)

grid.arrange(
  ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting, col=as.factor(ff_1$cluster))) + geom_point() +
    geom_point(data=as.data.frame(ff_1$centers), aes(eruptions, waiting), col='black', pch='*', cex=15) +
    labs(title = "kmeans seed 1\n", color = "ff1 cluster\n"), 
  ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting, col=as.factor(ff_2$cluster))) + geom_point() +
    geom_point(data=as.data.frame(ff_2$centers), aes(eruptions, waiting), col='black', pch='*', cex=15) +
    labs(title = "kmeans seed 1\n", color = "ff2 cluster\n"),
  ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting, col=as.factor(ff_300$cluster))) + geom_point() +
    geom_point(data=as.data.frame(ff_300$centers), aes(eruptions, waiting), col='black', pch='*', cex=15) +
    labs(title = "kmeans seed 1\n", color = "ff300 cluster\n"))

identical(ff_1, ff_2) # TRUE
identical(ff_1, ff_300) # TRUE
```

[image]

Now, let's change the seeds that will force `kmeans` to choose different  initial centroids and the results will be different, as can be seen from the following figure.

```
set.seed(1)
ff_1 <- kmeans(faithful, 2, iter.max = 1, nstart = 1)

set.seed(12)
ff_2 <- kmeans(faithful, 2, iter.max = 2, nstart = 1)

set.seed(123)
ff_300 <- kmeans(faithful, 2, iter.max = 300, nstart = 300)

grid.arrange(
  ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting, col=as.factor(ff_1$cluster))) + geom_point() +
    geom_point(data=as.data.frame(ff_1$centers), aes(eruptions, waiting), col='black', pch='*', cex=15) +
    labs(title = "kmeans seed 1\n", color = "ff1 cluster\n"), 
  ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting, col=as.factor(ff_2$cluster))) + geom_point() +
    geom_point(data=as.data.frame(ff_2$centers), aes(eruptions, waiting), col='black', pch='*', cex=15) +
    labs(title = "kmeans seed 12\n", color = "ff2 cluster\n"),
  ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting, col=as.factor(ff_300$cluster))) + geom_point() +
    geom_point(data=as.data.frame(ff_300$centers), aes(eruptions, waiting), col='black', pch='*', cex=15) +
    labs(title = "kmeans seed 123\n", color = "ff300 cluster\n"))

identical(ff_1, ff_2) # FALSE
identical(ff_1, ff_300) # FALSE
```

[image]

Comment: You write that the algorithm converges after the 2nd iteration, but then why is `identical(ff_1, ff_2)` true? Are the very first cluster centers chosen prior or during the first iteration? If they are chosen (randomly) during the first iteration, I simply don't get how `identical(ff_1, ff_300)` can ever be true.

Comment: @joe they are identical because the randomly chosen initial cluster centroids (the one chosen prior to the first iteration) is same for both `ff_1` and `ff_2`because you used the same seed.

Comment: My point was that here convergence obviously happens as soon as after the first iteration (and not after the second as you write), otherwise `ff_1` and `ff_2` would not be identical.

Comment: @joe sure that's correct, edited my post, thanks for pointing out.